# My brightness controls aren't working (Ubuntu 14.04), how to fix?

Tags: brightness

I use either the buttons or the ui but the brightness doesn't change.

What do I need to change to get brightness working?

I'm using a Toshiba Ultrabook in case it is relevant.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and specify your hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix was to edit

```
/etc/default/grub
```

changing:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to be

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and then

```
update-grub
```

and then reboot.

I'm on a Toshiba ultrabook though I've seen this fix work for other manufacturers hardware also.

Comment: How do you know this works for OP's hardware?

Comment: I am the original OP  :)

Comment: Oops, it is your question )))

Comment: no problem.  I post in case it help others and cos I didn't find the answer on askubuntu when searching originally

Comment: But specify hardware either way. It won't work for everyone.

Comment: Is toshiba ultrabook specific enough?  The thing is I have seen this fix work for at least three other manufactuers on various other forums.  So I was hesitant to state hardware in that light in case people thought the problem and the solution would _only_ work on the hardware I list.

Comment: It is not enough. There a dozen solutions for that. Each works with specific hardware. Please add the laptop model in the question title.

Comment: It's a Portege z835-P360.  I do not want to put it in the title because the fix simply isn'ty specific to that model or manufacturer.  It may not fix all computers true, but it's not specific to this model.

Comment: There are "acpi_osi=", "acpi_osi=Linux", other strings, then for Intel graphics xorg.conf should be updated, etc. I see no reason to advertise it as a universal solution.